# preg_match to find images with specific names

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm using this code to find all images with name begin thumb_

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
  $pattern = '/thumb_[\w\-]+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)/';
  $result = preg_match($pattern, $files[$i], $matches);
  echo $matches[0]."<br>";
}
```

I get this:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\imgs.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\imgs.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\imgs.php on line 31

thumb_Koala.jpg
thumb_Lighthouse.jpg
```

Comment: echo $matches[0]."<br>";

Comment: you're getting the error since the regex doesn't match the file . . .  you should likely check the value of `$result` to see if it's 1 or 0 or FALSE before trying to parse `$matches`.  You'd probably be better off using `glob()` or a substring search (e.g. `strpos`) than regex

Comment: LoL forget on that :)
Thank you ernie....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more simply...

```
<?php
foreach (preg_grep('/^thumb_[\w\-]+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$/', scandir('uploads')) as $path) {
    printf('<img src="uploads/%s" style="margin: 10px"><br>', $path);
}
```